# Laravel: How to update error views using vendor:publish

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

The Whoops view is showing whenever there is a 500 error, and on a 404, the "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found" view shows.

According to the documentation, I can override these with my own views by creating the files `/resources/views/errors/500.blade.html` and `/resources/views/errors/404.blade.html`

I thought I would use the Laravel views as a starting point though, so I ran the following command:

```
vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

I was expecting this to create the 500 and 404 files for me in the errors directory, but it didn't.  Is this a error?  Or should I be expecting something else?

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This command is only available in laravel `5.7` and higher.

What you can do instead is copy the files yourself from the github repo:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views

This folder contains all the files the command would publish into `views/errors`